# Prove that if $g\circ f$ is surjective and $$ is total and injective then $$ is surjective

Tags: functions, logic

I know that if $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $g(f(a_1))$ is defined for all $a_1$, and thus $f(a_1)$ is defined but after that, I'm confused

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ so that $g\circ f:A\to C$.

Fix $y\in B$. Since $g$ is total, then $g(y)\in C$.

Since $g\circ f$ is surjective and $g(y)\in C$, then there exists an $x\in A$ such that $g(f(x))=g(y)$.

Since $g$ is injective, then $f(x)=y$.

We have now shown that for all $y\in B$, there exists an $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$, so we conclude that $f$ is surjective.